# Cursor position in vi at opening of the file

Tags: bash, shell-script, vi, function

```
vishex ()
{ 
    echo '#!/bin/bash' > $1;
    chmod +x $1;
    vi $1
}
```

The goal of the above function is to have an alias for fast and comfortable creation of bash scripts. I would like that at the opening of the file the cursor would be not standing in the Shebang line but on a line below. I've tried something like `echo 'blabla\n', echo "blala\n", printf "blala\n"` without any result.

Comment: change `echo '#!/bin/bash' > $1;` to `echo -e '#!/bin/bash\n' > $1;`. Then follow Radovan's answer

Comment: One day you will regret this when you `vishex mygreatscript.sh` and lose dozens or hundreds of lines of code.  You are tempting Murphy.  So start the function with `[ -e "$1" ] && return 1`

Comment: @cas It's easy to avoid this if add check `[ -f "$1" ] && exit 1`

Comment: For a function, you want `return`, not `exit` (or bye-bye shell).  Or do it as chaos did it in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
vishex () 
{ 
    [ -e "$1" ] || echo -e '#!/bin/bash\n\n' > "$1";
    chmod +x "$1";
    vi "+normal G" +startinsert "$1"
}
```

- `[ -e "$1" ]` checks if the script already exists. If yes `echo` will not override it.
- `-e`  in echo enables interpretation of backslash escapes, such as `\n` for a newline. Then it inserts 2 newlines after the shebang line.
- `+normal G` runs the ex command `G` which jumps to the last line in the file.
- `+startinsert` switches directly to insert mode (you can also leave that, as it's not in the question mentioned).

---

So, when executing `vishex script` it looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

<- cursor is here
~
[...]
~
-- INSERT --                                                               3,1           All
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your *vi* is actually *vim*, from the manpage:

```
+[num]   For  the  first file the cursor will be positioned on line "num".
         If "num" is missing, the cursor will be positioned  on  the  last line.
```

Thus, use:

```
vi + "$1"
```

Comment: Actually this was a feature in the original `vi` as well, IIRC